# How to ignore properties with only a getter when using Object.assign()?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

I have an object source with no type defined, but represents a typed object. So that I'm using the Object.assign(target, source). But my class have properties which are getters (because they are results of calculations of the other properties).

An example:

```
source: {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  sum: 3
}

class SomeClass {
  a: number;
  b: number;

  get sum(): number {
    return a + b;
  }
}

someFunction() {
  let obj = new SomeClass();
  Object.assign(obj, source);
}
```

In the above situation, I get an error: 
*Cannot set property sum of [object Object] which has only a getter*.

Is there any way of the Object.assign() ignore those properties from the source object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Object.assign()` for that, [because](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object.

In other words, `Object.assign()` is driven by enumerable properties of the `source` and is not affected by the way the properties are defined in the target.

You have to implement your own function instead of `Object.assign()` which will skip properties that are not writable for the target, or find some library which does that.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution for this is to just have an empty setter:

```
get sum(): number {
    return a + b;
}

set sum(value) {}
```